# expected value of geometric distribution using "first-step analysis"

Tags: probability

How does this work? I'm particularly confused by "we've wasted one toss and are back to where we started." Are we back to where we started though? $E(X)$ (on the LHS of the equation) is the expected number of failures before the first success. But then we have "$(1+E(X))$ which is strange because why are we looking at $E(X)$ if we already looked at the first toss? Shouldn't it be $1 + E(X-1)$? Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: In the expression 1+E(X), X is the number of failures in subsequent tosses.

Comment: @herbsteinberg So X on the LHS is different from X on the RHS?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I guess what I'm confused about is how to distinguish X when we start from the first coin test versus when we start from the second coin toss.

Comment: Every time you start tossing a coin you expect to get $E(X)$ tails before you finally get a head. After you get a tail in the first toss, does it alter your coin or any probability of subsequent toss? No. That is why you expect to get another $E(X)$ tails before you see a head.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja So that makes sense but something that's confusing is this. Suppose $E(X)$ is 4. Given the first toss is tails, shouldn't the rest of the tail of toin cosses have a smaller expected value compared to the entire tail of toin cosses since we're already seen a first tail? Put concretely, need to see 3 more tails until we see a heads; we have 1 for the first tail and then we need to do $E(X)$ for the rest of the tail. But how could the $E(X)$ of the rest of the tail equal the $E(X)$ of the entire tail?

Comment: Put differently, does the game really restart because we need to keep track of previous tails

Comment: I think I vomited out that comment. A simple way of putting this is suppose $E(X)$ is 4 and we observe a tail on the first toss. We expect to see three more tails because $E(X)$ is four. But if we just "restart" the game, we're expecting four more tails which doesn't make sense given that we've $\textbf{already seen}$ one tail.

Comment: That is a common fallacy. Just because we have seen more tails in previous tosses does not mean the probability of getting head increases. Remember that the tosses are independent, including independent of previous toss.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja That makes sense: an example is saying "if we observe 10000 heads, the probability the next toss is heads is still 1/2." But I'm confused because expectation seems different since we're "considering history" / counting "pass tosses." What I mean is, given that we observe a tail, assuming $E(X)$ is 4, wouldn't we "use up" a tail?

Comment: $E(X)$ is the expected value of $X$ in the future, not past and future combined. In our case, $E(X)=4$ means if we start tossing coin we expect to see ADDITIONAL 4 tails in our future tosses. An extreme case is, if last year you have tossed $4$ tails, do you expect $0$ this year since $E(X)=4$?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja That also makes sense, but then I'm confused because what's the point of expectation then? Before I flip any coins, I expect to get four tails before I get a head (let's say because we run a simulation for a million tosses and we see before every head there's four tails). Then, I flip four tails in a row. Shouldn't on average I expect a head because $E(X)=4$? I get what you're saying: no you shouldn't because we restart the game; you should expect to see four more tails given that you've already seen four more tails.

Comment: But then it seems expectation is a bit useless because we can never "expect" something to be more and more likely to be true

Comment: Probability and expectation is useful for something that has not happened. Say you have a fair coin and you have tossed more tails in the past, does that mean you are more likely to get heads in the future? No. Then with the same logic you mentioned, probability is useless too

Comment: @beginner  I can see the confusion.  The answer to your question is yes.  The left hand side  X is the overall total.  The X on the right hand size is the total remaining after the first game.

Comment: Thank you very much!!